# How can I pinch and zoom an HTML 5 canvas with touch events?

Tags: html, canvas

How can I pinch and zoom an HTML 5 canvas with touch events?

Comment: 1. Catch touch events. 2. Write [code to pinch and zoom](http://phrogz.net/tmp/canvas_zoom_to_cursor.html). What have you tried so far?

Comment: @Phrogz if u have code of pinch and zoom please give me,

Comment: Seems to me that Phrogz included a link to some code.

Comment: @JocelynLECOMTE that doesnt have any code

Comment: @GAPS firebug is your friend :)

Answer (score 2):

Try jgesture library - it has many more nice events too.

http://jgestures.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

If you do not want to depend on jQuery, there is also [hammer.js](http://eightmedia.github.io/hammer.js/).